# coding a tabular form in html

Tags: html, layout

I'm trying to create a form that clients would complete via the web, so far I've resorted to using various tables butted up against each other to get the view I'm looking for, one of the issues is that when the tables are next to each other the borders appear twice as thick.

I think I could probably turn certain borders on and off but this would be a pain to manage, is there a better way I should be doing this?

My form looks something like this (jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/5AXKa/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #form table
    { 

        width:100%;
    }

    td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

    table
    {
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    #form
    {
        width:1000px;
        /*border:1px solid black;*/
    }

    .field
    {
        border-right:none;
    }

    table, tr, td
    {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }

    #Logo
    {
        width:30%;
    }

    #TestName
    {
        width:40%;
    }

    #TestNumber
    {
        width:30%;
    }

    #heading
    {
        height:70px;
    }

    .title
    {
        text-align:center;
    }

    .Data
    {
        border-left:none;
        border-right:none;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form">

        <table>
            <tr id="heading">
                <td id="Logo">LOGO GOES HERE</td>
                <td id="TestName">TEST NAME</td>
                <td id="TestNumber">TEST NUMBER</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>

        <table id="CommonData">
            <tr>
                <td class="field">CLIENT:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">SITE:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">Contract NO:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field">DUTY:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">TAG No:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">Loop No:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field">SYSTEM No:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">SYSTEM REF:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td class="field">DWG No:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field">CTP No:-</td>
                <td class="data"></td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr class="title">
                <td>INSTRUMENT / APPLIANCE</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="float:left;width:50%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">INSTRUMENT DETAILS:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SERIAL No:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>SIZE:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SERVICE DATA SHEET REF:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>POWER SUPPLY:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MODEL NO:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IP RATING:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RANGE/SPAN</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="float:right; width:50%">
            <tr>
                <td>INSTRUMENT TYPE</td>
                <td>TICK BOX</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PROXIMITY SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LIMIT SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FLOAT SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ULTRASONIC</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>THERMOCOUPLE</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PRESSURE SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>f
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TEMPERATURE SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FLOW SWITCH</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CONDUCITIVITY METER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TURBIDITY METER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CHEMICAL RESIDUAL ANALYSER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FLOW METER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PH METER</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr class="title">
                <td>MONITOR / CONVERTER</td>
            </tr>
        <table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>PLANT UNIT:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
                <td>INSTRUMENT TYPE:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SERIAL No:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
                <td>SPAN:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>POWER SUPPLY:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
                <td>OTHER:-</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="blah" style="width:100%"/></td>
            </tr>
        <table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link to your post.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't use tables for anything but tabular data

Comment: would using divs for something like this be hard, can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your table structure. If possible, use a single table, with one item on one row—there is normally no need to simulate printed forms (where you try to put everything on one sheet of paper) when designing a web form. Don’t use all uppercase, and put heading-like items in bold to clarify the structure of the form. Do not set widths for cells—it is part of the basic benefits of using tables that you can leave width allocation to browsers.

Your problems with borders are just one symptom of too complicated a design. When using a single table, adjacent browsers collapse when you just set `cellspacing=0` in the `table` tag or `border-collapse: collapse` in CSS.

Comment: the form has to be printed with all the various borders

Comment: If the form has to be printed, make it a PDF form. This is the way to ensure that it will be printed in a known format, to the extent such control is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a bunch of tables with a single div, you can use divs and specify the margin around the div.

Comment: so a main div and then divs inside that have margins specified

Answer (score 0):

This is a beginning.

Use a `fieldset` for each column.
Put every `label` and `input` in a `div`.

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    float: left;
}
label {
    clear: both; // Start the label at a new line
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
{
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><label for="field1">Field1</label><input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" /></div>
<div><label for="field1">Field2</label><input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" /></div>
```

etc...

Comment: looks like I need to set padding to 0 and margin to -1 to align fields against each other, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think so. In general I suggest that you use a reset style sheet (that sets margins and paddings to 0)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xvF3H/ I can get them to appear in columns now but how do I get them to appear next to each other, I used eric meyers css reset

Comment: You have to put field1 and field2 in one fieldset (which is the left column).
http://jsfiddle.net/AMexH/2/

(Please accept my answer if this is the way you want to make your form)

Comment: Still evaluating the best way for me to approach this, this does seem to be turning out to be the better one, otherwise im considering just doing one large table,

Comment: I updated http://jsfiddle.net/AMexH/3/ is there a nice way to get the borders to include the text box, if so I think this will be the way to go for me